# Border around masked video iframe

Tags: jquery, html, css, video, iframe

```
<div class="videoCircle">
<iframe width="250" height="250" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wcVkPoPsuNU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

this is my video div on which I have applied mask through css

```
.videoCircle {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 125px;
    border: 6px solid #fff;
    top: 320px;
    margin:0 45% 0 45%;
    z-index: 30000;
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, white 100%, black 100%);
}
```

My border is not visible anymore after I have applied -webkit-mask-image. Can I achieve this somehow (other ways are ok too)?

Comment: what you mean by "My border is not visible anymore", from your code there is border for  div element, and it seems to be working - [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/fu51m4x2/)

Comment: When I open it in google chrome it doesn't show me border: 6px solid #fff; from my code.

Comment: Have you tried different color other than `#fff`

Comment: Yes and it is not working. I have tried with .videoCircle:after {
content:'';
border: 6px solid red;
position: absolute;
z-index: 40000;
}

Comment: Is there any way to show video in circle instead of adding: -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, white 100%, black 100%);

Comment: I made it with    overflow:hidden;   Working now! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `-webkit-mask-image: ...` with `overflow: hidden`.

```
.videoCircle {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 125px;
  border: 6px solid green;
  top: 320px;
  margin: 0 45% 0 45%;
  z-index: 30000;
  overflow: hidden;
  // -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, white 100%, black 100%);
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bq3a4rsn/).